# Azure VM MVC website unity

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a MVC website, which using Dependency Injection "Unity", it is running fine on my local machine and also no problem on my old dedicated server (Window SEVER 2008 R2 SP1). When I move the website to Azure VM (Window SEVER 2008 R2 SP1), I got following error message;

Server Error in '/' Application.

The IControllerFactory 'Store.Factories.UnityControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The IControllerFactory 'Store.Factories.UnityControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The IControllerFactory 'Store.Factories.UnityControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +423
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +73
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +921
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

I cannot figure out why, Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved automatically by upgrading Unity from 2 to 4.